# How does assigns know where to look for the instance variable in integration tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've been following a rails tutorial and got to know the `assigns` method of Rspec.

This is how it's being used in an integration test:

```
class SomeTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "simplified test" do
    get '/some/path'
    #some assertions
    get '/other/path'
    assert_equal 'changed', assigns(:some_variable)
  end
end
```

Assigns seem to access the controller/view of the last call.

Is that so? how does `assigns` get to the instance variable `some_variable`?

It seems to imply there is some state being preserved in the integration test that is accessed from `assigns`.

Comment: It's a common Rails helper method to inspect variables set in the controller. It knows where to look because it knows which controller is being tested because the test created the controller specifically for testing it.

Comment: @estani you are talking about Controller Specs and generally, they start with something like `RSpec.describe BuzzsController, :type => :controller do`. Notice `BuzzController` passed in there. That is how it knows which controller to look for.

Comment: @tadman no there is no controller directly involved. As I said it's an integration test, so there is actually a call to a path that will be resolved by some controller, but there will be many calls and my questions is "how" this happens not what it does.

Comment: If you're processing a request there's a controller. It's probably the last controller to run.

Comment: @tadman I guess, but that means there is a state being held where the last controller (or every one called) get stored. I'm hopping to get more detailed info about this process.

Comment: If you're ever completely stumped as to what's going on, `raise method(:assigns).source_location.inspect` will tell you where that method is implemented so you can go and look at the source.

Comment: @tadman thanks that helped a lot. I'd post the answer here myself now, but I guess I can't because the Question is marked as duplicated. Do you still think that "how it works" is the same as "hat is does"? If not, please remove the flag.

Comment: I've had it re-opened if you have an answer to post.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that Rails treat Integration tests pretty much like functional ones, so the instance variables described in the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#instance-variables-available) for the latter works in the former. In integration tests these variables tend to be overwritten, so you'll access the state prior to your call.

That means that in an integration test you may access:

- @controller: the last controller being invoked
- @request: the last request sent
- @response: the last response object returned

`assings` just wraps the access to `@controller.view_assigns` where all the instance variables that will be available for the view are held.